# Jsch ssh with edittext android

Tags: java, android, xml, ssh, jsch

hello i have one problem, im using jsch to connectia via ssh to for example one device my code working but its using integrated username, password and host i want to create activity there write username password and host and after that connect and do some command for example "reboot"...when im typing ip adpress in edittext field, get data from there not fixed ip, ithink you can understant me and sorry for my bad english :) this is my code >>

Activity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ssh);

    Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_menu);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void onClick11 (View v) {
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                executeSSHcommand();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(1);
}


@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public void onClickct (View v) {
    new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                Compliancetest();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(1);
}

public void executeSSHcommand(){
    String user = "user";
    String password = "user";
    String host = "192.168.1.1";
    int port=22;
    try{

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setTimeout(10000);
        session.connect();
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand("reboot");
        channel.connect();
        channel.disconnect();

    }
    catch(JSchException e){

    }
}

public void Compliancetest(){
    String user = "user";
    String password = "user";
    String host = "192.168.1.1";
    int port=22;
    try{

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setTimeout(10000);
        session.connect();
        ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
        channel.setCommand("reboot");
        channel.connect();
        channel.disconnect();

    }
    catch(JSchException e){

    }
}
```

and my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar">
</include>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="IP Address" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/uname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="Username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="Password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="onClick11"
    android:text="@string/command" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="onCommand"
    android:text="@string/reboot" />
```

Comment: What's exactly the probkem?what do you mean by integrated user, pass...?

Comment: i want to use this from xml file for example string user = "edittextdata"
public void executeSSHcommand(){
    String user = "user";
    String password = "user";
    String host = "192.168.1.1";
    int port=22;
    try{

Comment: So you should get the text from your edittext by, edittext.gettext then save it in user, pass,....

Comment: can you show me how? sorry i am just new in java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance lets talk about getting ip from :

```
String ipName;
```

> EditText ip =findViewById(R.id.ip);
>
> ipName = ip.getText();

Put it in bottom.onclicklistener to do it after the edit text has been filled